# What are the state of the art to use vim as a java IDE

Tags: java, vim, ide

I am using vim to code in R,kdb,C++. In my new job I'll start java and I was hoping being able to keep vim.
There are a few similar subject that are pretty old on SO.
Say I want to be able to get

1. completion (like YouCompleteMe)
2. snipets (like ultisnips)
3. syntax checking (like syntactic)
4. syntax highlighting

I do not want to pay for it (well don't really care but the compny would not allow it). I know about

1. [eclim](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclim/?source=recommended)
2. [vrapper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vrapper/?source=recommended)
3. [vimplugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vimplugin/)

What are the +/- are there new contenders ?

EDIT: The general advice seems to be to stay on a vanilla IDE, though I'd be happy to hear about what people like/dislike about eclim,vrapper,vimplugin

Comment: Use a real `IDE`, one of the big three.

Comment: I never though I would see VIM and state of art in the same phrase. Jokes aside, Java really benefits from a good IDE, NetBeans is my favorite, but Eclipse have a bigger community and more third party add-ons, including that is the official Android IDE, both are open source and free, so give them a spin.

Comment: Your list of 4 is likely to grow; e.g. running tests and hyperlinking the failures, stacktraces, etc.  Proper Java IDEs (Eclipse/IntelliJ/NetBeans) are really integrated and offer many powerful features - you'll be severely limiting yourself by not trying one.

Comment: If you miss vim that much try Eclipse with [vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/) for vim-like editing

Comment: I have one problem with eclipse. It always closes my quotes for me, which I would rather do myself. I can't even edit HTML on eclipse, drives me nuts.

Comment: I love vim very much. I do (almost) any text editing in vim. My day job is java development. When I write java code, I do it in Eclipse... :(  with viplugin. I tried eclim, but finally removed it. the short-cut conflict is too annoying.

Comment: @statquant I didn't try vrapper, so I cannot give you more info on that.

Comment: @kent what is this shortcut conflicts you are refering about ?

Comment: A few years from today as a java developer I was sick about eclipse and its unstability so I try netbeans and then vim and then the jvi plugin for netbeans. The good part of jvi is that it's a port of some of the code from vim to java and not a emulation layer so most of the features like registers and macros just work. By now vim is my main editor and only use netbeans to start the debugger on legacy code but I have to do some non trivial tweaks to my vimrc to get a good working environment inside of vim and totally worth the effort

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is written in Java and supports it very well.  Are you working with in Java SE, EE, or ME?

If you are starting to learn Java you should stick with a plain editor and command line tools.  IDEs are for speed and ease of use.

Netbeans is another option but in my opinion Eclipse is better.

For Android development you could use Eclipse (with ADT plugin) or Android Studio.

Comment: FYI, the new Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, not Eclipse.  Google has stated they will continue to support Eclipse, but I suspect only half heartedly at best.  Ive looked at the new IntelliJ Android environment, very impressive.  They still have a bit of work to do, but very impressive indeed.

Comment: The only downside I see to Android Studio is they lead you to using Gradle.  I've started working with it and it's not bad but my company already has many build tools and frameworks.  Adding another causes overhead we didn't want. Even if it's the best and easiest build tools ever made it still requires some level of effort. (PS we use Eclipse for C++/C, NodeJS, PHP, etc. and now we aren't using it for Java lol.

Answer (score 2):

I use and quite like [viplugin](http://www.viplugin.com/index.htm) with Eclipse.  Eclipse is free, and viplugin doesn't cost much ($19 last time I checked).   I know you wanted to avoid paying for tools, but maybe you could spare a $20 for your craft.  I paid for my copy, which I also (quite legally) use at home.

Comment: +1. I am doing the same... it is the best (for me) option I can find between eclipse and vim..

Answer (score 0):

Sublime.  It is commercial, $70, but one of the best.  At work I have stopped using Eclipse completely in favor of Sublime with the SublimeLint and SublimeCLang plugins.

But, at home, I still use my beloved IntelliJ

Comment: I haven't given ST a try, since vim is just too great!. what kind of java application do you write? jee? when I write java, I do it still in eclipse, same as @CPerkins, I use viplugin. If it is really like what you said, I may try sublimeText. Can it do: Auto generate imports, auto getter/setter generation, quickfix, javaDoc support, debugging, remote debugging, checkstyle, framework integration (like spring, hibernate), maven integration, methods auto impl. (toString, equals, hashcode..) and many many more eclipse features?

Comment: the auto stuff, im sure you can find a plugin to do it.  I don't use any code generators of any kind, I'm just one of those crazy people that prefer to write it all out by hand.  If you want all those features you listed, IntelliJ is the way to go IMHO.  Sublime would be the way to go if you really know what your doing and are sick and tired of the IDE getting in the way.

Comment: They kind of work I do is high volume transaction systems for banks.  My stuff is typicaly too high of a load for JEE.  I usually use Spring or write my own specialized frameworks to get the job done.

Comment: Ok, you use spring, bean xml config, annotation, bean validation, Aop etc, can sublime Text do all those stuff? My feeling is, if vim cannot do some task well, sublime text either.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367961/does-sublime-text-2-wins-over-eclipse-for-java-development

Comment: the submlimelint and sublimeclang plugins allow deep enough analysis into the code where it recognizes annotations.  My team works exclusivly in annotations so our xml configs are typically only 2 or 3 parameters.  I guess the best way to put it is Sublime is a modern day Vim that can be extended with plugins written in python.  The features your asking about are full fledged IDE features, not a text editor feature.  We went sublime because all of my guys are 10 - 15+ years with Java and we were sick of IDE's getting in our way.  So we do it all by hand.

Comment: yes, I was asking IDE features. I guess that would be the point of OP too. I do think sublime is a good editor, otherwise there won't be so many users. But I doubt it could beat eclipse in java dev. I would try it by myself one day. BTW. vim plugins can be written in several programming languages (Perl, Python, Ruby, Tcl, Scheme...) and its native vimscript.